# Difference between BREAK and REJECT in PARSE

Tags: parsing, rebol, rebol3, red

Both in [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/parsing-summary.html#section-3) and [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/2013/11/041-introducing-parse.html), there are two PARSE key words: `break` and `reject` which have similar behavior: *break out of a match loop (such as any, some, while)*, the difference is that `break` *always indicating* **success** while `reject` *indicate* **failure**.
I know what it means literally, but can't figure out a proper scenario where which of the two keywords should be used.

```
blk: [ 1 #[none] 2 #[none] #[none] 4 5 6 #[none] ]
count: 0
result: parse blk [
    any [ 
            remove none! insert 2 
            if ((count: count + 1) >= 2) break
            | 
            skip
    ]
]
probe blk          ;will get [1 0 2 0 none 4 5 6 none]
probe result       ;will get false
probe count        ;will get 2
```

In the code above, either `break` or `reject` will produce the same result.

So anyone can show me what is the difference between these two keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth value produced by `break` depends on whether the minimum number of iterations in an iterative rule have been reached or not.

```
>> parse "aaabbb"  [ some [ "a" break ] to end]
== true
```

Here we have matched "a" at least once, and then broken out of the some rule and continued to the end.  This is true.

```
>> parse "aaabbb"  [ some [ "a" reject ] to end]
== false
```

Here although we matched "a" once, reject causes the some rule to fail.

See [Carl's blog](http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/r3blog.r?view=0277) for more details.